# installation of UGS(LINUX) for my CNC Plotter

Tags: java, maven-3

Trying installing Universal-G-Code-Sender-master.zip contents. And when I try running ./run_platform command from console, I get the error message in last stages of installtionas under. Unable to reproduce complete details due to text limitations.
.

```
...
[INFO] ugs-classic ........................................ SUCCESS [  5.709 s]
[INFO] ugs-platform-parent ................................ SUCCESS [  0.508 s]
[INFO] ugs-platform-branding .............................. SUCCESS [  3.639 s]
[INFO] ugs-platform-ugslib ................................ SUCCESS [  9.734 s]
[INFO] ugs-platform-ugscore ............................... FAILURE [  1.809 s]
[INFO] ugs-platform-visualizer ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-plugin-workflow ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-gcode-editor .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-surfacescanner ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ProbeModule ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] DowelModule ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] GcodeTools ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-plugin-jog ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-plugin-setup-wizard ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-welcome-page .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-plugin-joystick ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-plugin-cloud-storage .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-plugin-toolbox ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-plugin-dro ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-plugin-designer ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-plugin-filebrowser .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-plugin-console ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ugs-platform-app ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:48 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-02-24T08:34:53+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (compile) on project ugs-platform-ugscore: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :ugs-platform-ugscore
```

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop. And Java/Maven versions are as under :

```
jimmy@jimmy-System-Product-Name:~$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.17 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu220.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu220.04, mixed mode, sharing)

jimmy@jimmy-System-Product-Name:~$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.17, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-60-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
jimmy@jimmy-System-Product-Name:~$ 

Path for Java and Maven as under:
jimmy@jimmy-System-Product-Name:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/share/java

jimmy@jimmy-System-Product-Name:~$ echo $MAVEN_HOME
/usr/share/maven
jimmy@jimmy-System-Product-Name:~$
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Interestingly, using another UGS-Platform(Linux) version, with associated command ./ugsplatform , I can successfully control my CNC Plotter.My Plotter project could be seen at you tube.com/@danjunk-DIY  handle. On windows10 I don't have any sort of problems in running UGS

Comment: Did you by chance read the link supplied by the error and see if you have other plugins causing this error?  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: thank you. I read it. But I found an answer for a similar problem faced by some one on Stackoverflow forums. Some one suggested to use ;sudo apt-get install -y icedtea-netx . When I tried it my problem seems resolved. Now the UGS platform GUI is accessible and I am able to control my machine. My problem was related to Package 'openjdk-6-jre' had no installation candidate.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: Read the `[ERROR]` lines, and do what they suggest